# Error in IE7 when using jQuery.blockUI() plugin

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, blockui

When I'm using blockUI() for show modal form I've got error in jquery.js:
Invalid argument (line 1061) (jquery.js)
At sting "elem[ name ] = value" in .attr() method.

JavaScript code:
Copy code

```
$('#deviceAddFormButton').click(function() {
    $.blockUI({
      message: $('#deviceAdd')
    })
})
```

HTML is just ..., nothing extraordinary

I'm using jQuery 1.3.2, blockUI 2.35. This error was thowing only in IE (Safari, Opera, Chromium, FireFox looks good:)

Comment: Are you sure it's this that's throwing the error? If so, which versions of jQuery and blockUI are you using?

Comment: An error was throwing when I cliked on a button. I'm using jquery 1.3.2, blockUI 2.35

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same problem, and I solved it by not using certain CSS items in the blockUI css option if I detect IE6 or 7.

For some reason, setting things like opacity causes jQuery to throw an error rather than ignore it.