# why doesn't .html() work in internet explorer 7

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7, asp.net-mvc-partialview

i have an asp.net-mvc site and i am getting weird behavior in internet explorer 7 on one page where the html result of an ajax call isn't showing up on the screen. This works perfect in Firefox, Chrome and IE8.

I first thought it was ajax related but to simplify and isolate the issue i got this to NOT work in IE7

```
$("#cupcakeOfMonthYear").live("click", function () {

       $('#cupcakeOfMonthCalendar').html("ffffff");
 });
```

Again, this works perfect in Firefox, Chrome and IE8 but when i change to compatibility mode to get the IE7 experience, the whole div area goes blank (instead of refreshing with the updated html).

Is this a bug in IE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured out the issue.  i was calling

```
.html(data)
```

**on the table selector itself** and it seems like IE7 doesn't like this.  i put a div surrounding the table and when the table came back from the ajax call. i called

```
.html(data)
```

on the outer div and that worked fine.  It actually makes sense as .html() doesn't seem to include the outer html but i guess all modern browsers figure it out and do the right thing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Which jquery blocking library (and which version) are you using ?

I mostly know of [blockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview)

Which seems to have a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284839/error-in-ie7-when-using-jquery-blockui-plugin) on your problem.

Comment: i removed the blockUI code from the question as i tested after removing this code and it still didn't work

Comment: what's in the 'data' content when you use IE7 ?

Comment: i updated my question at the end regarding the data.  I hard coded the response to some simple text and it still doesn't work in IE7.  ie8, ff and chrome is fine

Comment: now i just did some more testing and it has nothing to do with ajax call.  if all i do in the event handler is: $('#cupcakeOfMonthCalendar').html("ffffff"); it still doesn't work in IE7. i have updated the question to be simpler now that i have this isolated

Comment: in that case, would [that help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178507/jquery-html-not-displaying-any-data-in-ie7-but-ie8-works)

Comment: i added an answer as i figured out why IE7 was causing an issue